# Is it possible to set up assigned access for a Win 8.1 store app on Windows 10?

Tags: windows-store-apps, embedded, windows-10, kiosk-mode

I can successfully run a windows 8.1 store app without any issues however I cannot get it to work with assigned access on Windows 10. Is it even supported? or do I have to migrate the app to a UWP app?

On one of my windows installation it doesn't even appear in the list of available apps. On another installation it appears as an app but just immediately exits when the application starts.

Answer (score 0):

Try to set assigned access for windows 10 application (not for Windows 8.1 app). Yes, it is supported on Pro, Enterprise and Education versions.
 You can set it by different ways like it described in this topic:
 [Set up a kiosk on Windows 10 Pro, Enterprise, or Education](https://technet.microsoft.com/itpro/windows/manage/set-up-a-kiosk-for-windows-10-for-desktop-editions)

Comment: Sorry my question probably needs clarification. Can you set up assigned access using a win 8.1 store app on windows 10 ?